# How to work with all the monadic structures when they are nested deep?

Tags: scala, monads

Im trying to learn how to write more functional code in Scala, however im finding it difficult not to pull values out of the monadic structures but instead use map/flatmap etc to manipulate values. This is easy when working with a single monad but how do I scale this to work with structures as below.

For example what would be the idiomatic way to transforming the value inside `JsResult`?

```
Option[Future[JsResult[LoginResponse]]]
```

Comment: The answer will depend to some degree on what each level means, and what you're planning to do with these things. Without knowing more, I'd probably flatten the `Future` and `JsResult` into a single `Future` level, then move the `Option` inside the `Future`, and then (if I had a Cats or Scalaz dependency) turn the resulting thing into an `OptionT[Future, LoginResponse]`.

Comment: a) http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html b) http://atnos-org.github.io/eff-cats/

Comment: @Reactormonk Monad Transformers might be an idea - if you have any sample code on how the poster could use them for his example : Option[Future[JsResult[LoginResponse]]] that would be great.  I've put my best effort as an answer - but it would be good to see if there is something better

Answer (score 1):

Nested monads of a different types can be tricky, since for comprehensions require the Monads in it to be the same type.  You can either do:

Lots of nested for's

```
val mappedValue = for (fut <- deepMonad) yield {
  for (opt <- fut) yield { 
    for (bool <- opt) yield {
      //some logic
    }       
  }
}
```

or you can make a util which hides it away for you.

If you're looking at a specific structure which you use commonly in your project, and you want to stick with pure Scala, you can make something like below to do maps / foreach.

E.g.

```
object MyUtils {

  implicit class MyWrapper[A](deepMonad: Option[Future[Option[A]]]) {

    def fmap[B](f: A => B) = {
      for (fut: Future[Option[A]] <- deepMonad) yield {
        for (opt: Option[A] <- fut) yield {
          for (b: A <- opt) yield {
            f(b)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    def myForeach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
      for (future <- deepMonad) {
        for (opt <- future) {
          for (b <- opt) {
            f(b)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

object Test extends App {

  import MyUtils._

  val deepMonadExample:Option[Future[Option[Boolean]]] = Some(Future.successful(Some(true)))

  val x: Option[Future[Option[String]]] = deepMonadExample.fmap { 
    case v:Boolean => "Result: "+v 
  }
  x.myForeach{ v => println(v) }

}
```

If you are willing to use Scalaz you can make a more generic util by using the Monad class.  There are some prebuilt implicits in Scalaz which will make Option, Future, and others work out the box.  However classes like JsResult does not have a scalaz Monad instance, so you need to make one.

E.g.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsSuccess, JsError, JsResult}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz.Monad

//this creates the fmap method
object HandleDeepMonads {

  import scala.language.higherKinds
  import scalaz.Monad
  import scalaz.Scalaz._

  implicit class ThreeMonadMap[M[_] : Monad, M2[_] : Monad, M3[_] : Monad, A](v: M[M2[M3[A]]]) {
    def fmap[B](f: A => B): M[M2[M3[B]]] = {
      for (a <- v) yield
        for (b <- a) yield
          for (c <- b) yield f(c)
    }
  }

}

//Since JsResult has no native Monad in scalaz - you can make your own one
object MyCustomMonads {

  implicit object JsResultMonad extends Monad[JsResult] {
    def point[A](a: => A): JsResult[A] = JsSuccess(a)

    def bind[A, B](fa: JsResult[A])(f: A => JsResult[B]): JsResult[B] = fa match {
      case JsSuccess(v, _) => f(v)
      case e@JsError(_) => e
    }
  }

}

object Test extends App {

  import HandleDeepMonads._
  import MyCustomMonads._
  import scala.language.higherKinds
  import scalaz.Scalaz._

  val deepMonadExample: Option[Future[JsResult[String]]] = Some(Future.successful(JsSuccess("Hello")))
  val deepMonadExample2: Option[Future[JsResult[Boolean]]] = Some(Future.successful(JsError(Nil)))
  val deepMonadExample3: Option[Future[Option[Boolean]]] = Some(Future.successful(Some(true)))
  val deepMonadExample4: Option[Future[JsResult[Boolean]]] = None

  // Some(successful(JsSuccess("Result: true")))
  val x = deepMonadExample.fmap {
    "Result: " + _
  }
  // Some(successful(JsError()))
  val x3 = deepMonadExample3.fmap {
    "Result: " + _
  }
  // Some(successful(Some("Result: Hello")))
  val x2 = deepMonadExample2.fmap {
    "Result: " + _
  }
  // None
  val x4 = deepMonadExample4.fmap {
    "Result: " + _
  }
}
```

If you can simplify your monad to 2 deep, you may be able to use Scalaz's stock standard monad transformers (as suggested in the comments, E.g. OptionT).  I've seen them working at 2 deep quite well, but I've never used them in a more nested state though.